# Map Search Bar in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I want to add a "search bar" at the top on `Google Maps v2` as shown on this little picture I snipped from Google play.

[image: Google Map bar..]

How do I go about doing that? thanks

Comment: I have the maps already as well as added the Location 'button' at the far right using the setLocationEnabled()

Comment: maybe this can help you http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: @Yume117, you should write your comment as an answer. It worked for me too. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @An-droid I am using [wptrafficanalyzer](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-geocoding-showing-user-input-location-on-google-map-android-api-v2/) 

Instead of using  **`public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity`** , I am using  **`public class MainActivity extends Activity`**. Everything is working fine except when I click the button to search my application gets crashed. What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be a late answer but there should be an answer to this very common need.

In this what we basically need to do is use `Google Geocoder` to search for the address mentioned by user in the text box.

We can do it this way,

```
Geocoder geo = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
List<Address> gotAddresses = null;
try {
    gotAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(locationName[0], 1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This method returns a list of available addresses, in this code we are accepting only 1 address, we can get more than one addresses if needed by changing the value of last parameter in the above method. Then,

```
Address address = (Address) gotAddresses.get(0);

LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());

String properAddress = String.format("%s, %s",
address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address.getAddressLine(0) : "",
address.getCountryName());

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude())).draggable(true)
            .title(properAddress)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));
```